# How to get Bootstrap to not interfere with my button background colors set in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In this implementation of a button menu, how can I get the selected button to have the class `buttonDisplayTypeSelected` and others buttons to have `buttonDisplayTypeUnSelected`:

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/73h46odc/3

It works when the page is displayed, and it works when I don't use Bootstrap classes, but **how can I get the correct background colors for the buttons with Bootstrap** ?

```
  <span ng-repeat="displayType in displayTypes">
      <button ng-class="(displayType.idCode == currentDisplayTypeIdCode) ? 'buttonDisplayTypeSelected' : 'buttonDisplayTypeUnselected'" class="btn btn-default btn-xs "
              ng-click="selectDisplayType(displayType.idCode)">{{displayType.title}}</button>
  </span>
```

---

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    $scope.currentDisplayTypeIdCode = 'topTen';

    $scope.displayTypes = [
        {idCode: 'all', title: 'Show All'},
        {idCode: 'topTen', title: 'Top 10'},
        {idCode: 'favorites', title: 'Favorites'}
    ];

    $scope.selectDisplayType = function (displayTypeIdCode) {
        $scope.currentDisplayTypeIdCode = displayTypeIdCode;
    }    

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `bootstrap` add a style when a button is focused *(click on a button and then click on white background then button gets the actual color u need to get, this is because when you click on the white background button will gets blur and styles sets to the button through focus get removed)*, check the below image

[image]

what you need to do is simply override that `:focus` style as

```
.buttonDisplayTypeSelected, .buttonDisplayTypeSelected:focus {
    background-color: tan;
}
```

here is the updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4aj8w7h9/)